# Transform a Swift sequence in to adjacent pairs

Tags: swift, functional-programming, sequence

Given I've got an array in Swift such as `[1,2,3,4]`, a method `pairs()` will transform it in to the array of tuples: `[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`.

Here are some more examples of how `pairs()` should behave:

- `pairs([])` should return `[]` as it has no pairs.
- `pairs([1])` should also return `[]`, as it has no pairs.
- `pairs([1,2])` should be `[(1,2)]`. It has just one pair.

I can write code to do this for `Array`, but I'd like to have `pairs()` available as an extension on `Sequence`, so that it returns a `Sequence` of the pairs. This would make it useable on any sequence, and compatible with methods such as `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc.

How do I go about creating a `Sequence` like this? And how do I write the method to transform any `Sequence` in this way so that it can be used as flexibly as possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use `zip()` and `dropFirst()` if we define an extension 
on the `Collection` type:

```
extension Collection {
    func pairs() -> AnySequence<(Element, Element)> {
        return AnySequence(zip(self, self.dropFirst()))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for p in array.pairs() {
    print(p)
}
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

More examples:

```
print(Array("abc".pairs()))
// [("a", "b"), ("b", "c")]

print([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].pairs().map(+))
// [3, 5, 7, 9]

print([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2].pairs().filter(<))
// [(1, 4), (1, 5), (5, 9)]
```

---

(Unlike I wrote in the first version of this answer ...) this
approach is not safe when applied to a `Sequence`, because it is 
not guaranteed that a sequence can be traversed multiple times
*non-destructively.*

Here is a direct implementation with a custom iterator type
which works on sequences as well:

```
struct PairSequence<S: Sequence>: IteratorProtocol, Sequence {
    var it: S.Iterator
    var last: S.Element?

    init(seq: S) {
        it = seq.makeIterator()
        last = it.next()
    }

    mutating func next() -> (S.Element, S.Element)? {
        guard let a = last, let b = it.next() else { return nil }
        last = b
        return (a, b)
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    func pairs() -> PairSequence<Self> {
        return PairSequence(seq: self)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
print(Array([1, 2, 3, 4].pairs().pairs()))
// [((1, 2), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (3, 4))]
```

Comment: @MartinR, you also need to add check that `Self.SubSequence.Element == Self.Element`, otherwise `pairs` return type wouldn't match

Comment: @user28434: The updated Swift 4 code compiles and runs in my Xcode 9.2. Note that I changed the return type to a sequence of `(Element, SubSequence.Element)` – You *can* add that constraint, but you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the grok of the custom iterator. Really useful and enlightening answer!