# How to create an array of Tuples from an array of Double?

Tags: swift

I've been struggling to find the proper swift way to do this.

I'm sure it can be done in 1 line of code.

I've got this: `[Double]`

I would like to transform it to this: `[(Double, Double)]`

The array of `Tuples` has to be created like this (from the array of Double) :

(Double at index 0, Double at index 1), (Double at index 1, Double at index 2)  ...

I have tried with `map` or `zip` method.

But I seem to not be able to write in the code the `(i, i+1), (i+1, i+2)` logic for the construction of the Tuple.

```
let tupleArray = doubleArray.map { ($0, $1) }
```

Comment: humm, I guess I will remove the last one in the array of Double

Comment: @mag_zbc yikes didn't read the question properly >.<

Comment: You are totally correct, this answer could have helped me. I was not searching with the appropriate keywords (sequence and adjacent pairs were the key here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let doubles: [Double] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
let tuples = zip(doubles.dropLast(), doubles.dropFirst()).map { ($0, $1) }
```

Result:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

@Edit

As pointed out in comments you can use even shorter form:

```
Array(zip(doubles, doubles.dropFirst()))
```

I'd consider NOT skipping `.dropLast()`, just to make code more obvious.

Comment: Can you explain the dropLast and dropFirst in your zip? The logic behind it

Comment: @Balanced print them and you'll get it.

Comment: dropLast() - like the documentation says: "Returns a subsequence containing all but the specified number of final elements."
It does not remove the item from an array; it's just skipped when iterated.

Similar applies for dropFirst - first element is skipped, so iterating over array.dropFirst() starts from second item

Comment: Perfect answer then. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can omit the `.dropLast()`  ...

Comment: @MartinR, you're right. Result sequence is the same length as the shorter input sequence

Comment: Slightly shorter (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/49272932/1187415): `let tuples = Array(zip(doubles, doubles.dropFirst()))`

Answer (score 2):

You can create array of indexes from your array without last index and then you can just create tuple from element at this index and at next index

```
let tupleArray = doubleArray.indices.dropLast().map { (doubleArray[$0], doubleArray[$0+1]) }
```

> ```
> [(0.1, 0.2), (0.2, 0.3), (0.3, 0.4)]
> ```